# Running too much php-cgi.exe process in Apache VirtualHost on Windows

Tags: php, apache, cgi, virtualhost, fastcgi

I have a virtualhost configurated like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin name@ganydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/portal/web"
  ServerName portal

  <Directory "C:/xampp/www/portal/web">

    Require all granted


    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>  
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/project/web/bundles>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
  <Files ~ "\.php$">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FcgidWrapper "C:/Xampp/php-7.1.8-nts/php-cgi.exe" .php
  </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure it is properly well conigurated because I have 6 processes working and sometimes I get an 500 error with the following messatge at the bottom: `Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14 mod_fcgid/2.3.9`. I its weird seeing php5.6 here because it is the principal version installed in this Apache (it is sol old) but not uset in this virtualhost.

If somebody can give me any tip I would appreciate it so much.